# ShoppingCart in Java

Tags: java, jsp

i have a `Product` class and `CartItem` class that holds the product, and a `shoppingCart` class that contains the methods for adding/removing items from the cart.

I am currently using an XML file to store the products. How would you display a list of products in a JSP page. How do you iterate through the list of products, listing each products name, description, and size and its price?

Comment: i couldn't understand it completely, but it sounds to me like you should look at jibx

Comment: Ok forget about the XML, generally how would you display a list of products in a JSP page. How do you iterate through the list of products, listing each products name, description, and size and its price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how would you display a list of products in a JSP page. How do you iterate through the list of products, listing each products name, description, and size and its price*

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a collection. Use EL `${}` to access and display bean properties. Use HTML `<table>` to markup it as a table.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.name}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.size}</td>
            <td>${product.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: how will i be adding items in to ${products} with reference to the above code.

Comment: Just in the controller. In plain vanilla servlet, that would be `request.setAttribute("products", products);`.

Comment: and products in request.setAttribute("products", products); will be the Arraylist<Product> ?

Comment: Yes, just the list of products, as you mentioned in your question. I.e. `List<Product>`.