# Class objects and JSP

Tags: java, class, jsp, scope

I have a class Products, which has the attributes name, description and price.

I intend to populate products in the application scope of my project. How do I go about achieving that?

Secondly, upon populating the products, I want to be able to display each product in a table in a JSP page. Each product will have its own table, listing its name,description and price and an add to cart button

Comment: Hi user478636, this site works much better when there is only one question per question. Could you please remove the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I intend to populate products in the application scope of my project. How do I go about achieving that?*

So you want to populate it once during webapp's lifetime? Use a `ServletContextListener`.

```
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override 
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        List<Product> products = loadItSomehow();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("products", products);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way the products will be available in every servlet by

```
List<Product> products = (List<Product>) getServletContext().getAttribute("products");
```

and in every JSP by

```
${products}
```

---

> *Secondly, upon populating the products, I want to be able to display each product in a table in a JSP page. Each product will have its own table, listing its name,description and price and an add to cart button*

So you want to categorize the products? Have a `List<Category>` then where `Category` class has a `List<Product>`, or use a `Map<String, List<Product>>` where the key is the category name.

As to how to display it, that's already been answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457310/shoppingcart-in-java).